# Context issue with Backbone view render function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to include an optional argument in my Backbone view's render function, like this:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#app',

        initialize: function(){
                _.bindAll(this,'render');
                this.listenTo(app.collection.sellables,'reset', this.render);
        },

        render: function(sellableId){
                if(typeof sellableId == "undefined"){
                        var sellable = app.collection.sellables.first();
                }
                else{
                        var sellable = app.collection.sellables.get(sellableId);
                }
                var view = new SellableView({model: sellable});
                this.$('#sellables').append(view.render().el);
        },
});
```

The first time this view renders, it occurs because the `app.collection.sellables` collection gets reset after receiving some data from the server. When this reset occurs, the view's render function gets called, but instead of being called with `sellableId` as undefined, the `sellableId` is equal to the `app.collection.sellables` variable, which is causing errors.  To clarify, the view's render function is being called because of this:

```
app.collection.sellables.reset(data.skus);
```

Why would my render function be receiving the collection as an argument rather than the argument being undefined?

Also, if I render the view manually, it works correctly and the sellableId argument is undefined as expected:

```
var app.view.app = new AppView;
app.view.app.render();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding your `render` to `"reset"` right here:

```
this.listenTo(app.collection.sellables,'reset', this.render);
```

From the [Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog):

> - **"reset"** (collection, options) — when the collection's entire contents have been replaced.

So a handler for a `"reset"` event always gets the collection as its first argument. Keep in mind that a JavaScript function's arguments are determined when the function is called, not when the function is defined.

You have a few options. You could bind something else to the `"reset"` event:

```
initialize: function() {
    //...
    this.listenTo(app.collection.sellables, 'reset', this.been_reset);
},
been_reset: function() {
    this.render();
}
```

You could leave `render` without arguments (like a standard `render`) and have a separate function to handle the arguments:

```
render: function() {
    return this.append_model(app.collection.sellables.first());
},
append_model: function(sellable) {
    var view = new SellableView({model: sellable});
    this.$('#sellables').append(view.render().el);
    return this;
}
```

Then you'd call `view.append_model(app.collection.sellables.get(sellableId))` to add a specific model.